# Why does `xvfb-run glxgears` fail with an swrast error?

Tags: linux, opengl, xvfb

xvfb is supposed to let me run X programs in a headless environment. But when I run `xvfb-run glxgears`, I get:

```
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

When I run `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose xvfb-run glxgears`, I get:

```
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

I'm running stock Lubuntu 13.10 x64 with Intel Ivy Bridge integrated graphics. libgl1-mesa-dri is installed and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so exists. Running as root doesn't help.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just if anyone finds this old question, there is a solution to that mentioned in a [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=904851) linked from another unix.stackexchange [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137567/glx-extension-not-working-properly-with-xvfb). It was enough to change the default server parameters (`-s`/`--server-args`) from `-screen 0 640x480x8` to `-screen 0 640x480x24`, i.e. anything with the 24 color depth.

Comment: To be clear, it's `xvfb-run --server-args "-screen 0 1920x1080x24"` (quoted server arguments).